# nested structures (web services)

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, web-services, data-structures

I have a structure of data like this:

Method `SIOrderRate` gets an **orderData** structure.

- apiKey STRING
- userHash STRING
- orderData STRUCTURE
- courier STRING
- lang STRING

**orderData** has a field:

- sizeData ARRAY STRUCTURE

**sizeData** has parameters:

- width INT
- height INT
- depth INT
- weight INT
- COD FLOAT
- INS INT
- content STRING

> Dim danePrzesylki As BazyPolaczenia.SenditAPI.orderData = New
>   BazyPolaczenia.SenditAPI.orderData
>
> ```
> Dim danePaczki(0) As BazyPolaczenia.SenditAPI.singleSizesData
> danePaczki(0) = New BazyPolaczenia.SenditAPI.singleSizesData
> danePaczki(0).width = 100
> danePaczki(0).height = 100
> danePaczki(0).depth = 10
> danePaczki(0).weight = 10
> danePaczki(0).COD = 0
> danePaczki(0).INS = 5
> danePaczki(0).content = "Test"
>
> //...
> danePrzesylki.sizesData = danePaczki
> //...
> ```

Here I'm calling a method:

```
send.SIOrderRate(apiKey, userHash, danePrzesylki, "ups", "pl")
```

I get message error: **"Do not select any packages to be sent"**, but I should receive a price.

Comment: You haven't asked a question, nor have you provided enough information for anyone to answer the question.  Can you provide the code for the send.SIOrderRate() method?

Comment: You're right.

I can't provide the code of SIOrderRate() method cause it's a web service's method from SenditAPI system (courier service which I want to integrate with my online shop). I have a problem because it seems that - `danePrzesylki.sizesData = danePaczki` doesn't work well. I don't know how to assign this structure. 

Send is an object of SenditAPI, so I can call methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this SenditAPI system so I can help you. If you use `danePrzesylki.sizesData` field, your fourth parametes in SIOrderRate() method cannot be "ups". UPS does not provide this kind of packages.

Try this when you call this method:

```
send.SIOrderRate(apiKey, userHash, danePrzesylki, "inpost", "pl")
```

Because only inpost uses this field so now it should be everything correct.